# The inverse of sum of two positive matrices with almost orthogonal supports

Tags: matrix-theory, norms, matrix-inverse

I am interested to find an approximate formula for 
$$A  (A+B)^{-1} A\ ,$$
for two positive matrices $A$ and $B$ whose supports are almost orthogonal. 
If the support of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal then, 
$$A  (A+B)^{-1} A=A .$$

The question is how this formula is modified if the support of $A$ and $B$ are *almost* orthogonal. More specifically, let $A$ and $B$ be two positive matrices with trace one, i.e. two density operators. Suppose the $l_1$-norm of $A-B$ is larger than or equal to $2-\epsilon$, i.e. 
$$\|A-B\|_1\ge 2-\epsilon\ $$
 where $\epsilon \ge 0.$ Then, for $\epsilon=0$, the support of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal, which implies$A  (A+B)^{-1} A=A .$

The $\textbf{question}$ is how this formula is corrected for nonzero, but small $\epsilon>0$. Can we find a bound on    $\|A  (A+B)^{-1} A-A \|$?